# Converting UTC datetime to PST in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model which is the following:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    capacity = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

Given my model and my settings.py which has `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`. My goal is to display my times as 'US/Pacific' on my front-end. This unfortunately is not working out for me. If I create a model and do the following:

```
CapacityStatus.objects.create(capacity=current_status, active=active_until)
```

Then

```
new_record = CapacityStatus.objects.create(full_capacity=current_status, active_until=active_until)
new_record.save()
new_record.created_at.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))
```

If I send new_record back to the front end in my context dictionary my application shows the time in UTC. Is there anyway to make it so that the time is based on the user's time zone or at least 'US/Pacific'?

Comment: Consider sending data to the client in UTC format and the using [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to do the conversion client side (and also before POSTing said data back to the server, in reverse)

Comment: I wan't to avoid Javascript

Comment: My hope is to have the time reflect a user's timezone.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst: You may need to 'guess' the client's timezone based on data received from the client, which may require JS. Another alternative could be to have the user choose their timezone as a personal config option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the timezone template tag in your template:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "US/Pacific" %}
{{ created_at }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

The docs also show how to get a users' timezone and store it in the session.

Comment: I just saw this. I am aiming for a user's time zone. This fits for only one timezone.

Comment: Sounds like you need the TimezoneMiddleware example on that same page of the docs.